# CAML query for returning a single field

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, caml-query, caml

I'm trying to get a single field from a list.
The list has columns like this:

> Office365Account - Type: Person
>
> Email Address - Type: Email
>
> Manager - Type: Person

Basically what I want to do is find the manager associated with the current user of the system.

In SQL I'd do it something like this:

```
SELECT Manager FROM organizationContactsList WHERE Office365Account = currentuser
```

I'm pretty sure a CAML query is what I need to (or at least should) use, but I've just begun with SharePoint/SharePoint App programming and the structure of CAML queries baffle me. Any pointers on what this would look like in CAML?

Comment: Are you using onpremise sharepoint or sharepoint online?

Comment: SharePoint Online; this is for a App written using the JavaScript Object Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following CAML query :

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="Office365Account" />
    <Value Type="Integer">
      <UserID />
    </Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

Comment: Ah this makes more sense. And to get the UserID for the current user I'd do: `currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser().get_id()` I think this will solve my issue.

Comment: For current user you don't need to pass an ID. You can try as it is. If there is problem you can try with ID also.

Comment: Oh I see. `<UserID />` assumes that you're talking about the integer userid for the current user, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, i am assuming Office365Account is a User field.

Comment: Very good. That simplifies things! (It is a User field in my case.)

Comment: Looking at this closer, I see it will get me a collection of items from the row that matches the query. Could you clarify how I would then choose to look at only the manager field and get info from it. For example I would like to get the title of the manager or the id, etc.

Comment: Perhaps something like: `items["Manager"].get_title();` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use CAML for this, but a simple REST call would spit out the manager if you supply the user's claim.

`http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@a,propertyName='Manager')?@a='{userClaim}'`

There's a good blog post about pulling User Profile Properties from REST here: http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html

Comment: Ah very good. I'll keep this in mind too, and determine which best fits my needs.

Comment: Oh I see, they have to have a manager associated with their actual account's properties for a query like this to work. In my case our organization doesn't have that manager field filled out, and instead we're using a separate list that groups people and their managers.

Comment: If you can't use people service then you can just use a REST query to your lookup list; still arguably more efficient than CAML (and a more future proof solution given the deprecation of the SOAP services).